# Need suggestions for a removable or mobile fence for a parking spot next to the garage

Tags: fence

Below is the layout of the space that I want to close with a fence. What is not shown in the picture is a large driveway that goes from the street to both the garage and the parking spot that I want to close.
My plan is to fix the front view of my property, the house that is next to me, on the left side is a mirror image of my house. All the houses on the street are the same model and mine is the only one that has no front fence next to the garage. My plan is to keep the parking spot as it is (could use it for storing a small boat or to part an utility trailer) but to mask this with a fence and a gate. The gate will be used for accessing the backyard and  the front side of the fence should be removable so I can get the boat or the trailer out of there.

The brown strip next to the garage is for flowers. The grey square at the end of the far side of the space is a gate and behind that is the backyard and you can guess a patio there

I am looking for a smart idea to close that area and to preserve the accessibility of that space.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does the fence have to be removable, or are you open to the idea of a large gate?  What type if fencing are you planning to use (chain link, wood, vinyl, etc.)?

Comment: I would like to use a wood fence made of horizontal planks. A wide gate might work but I am afraid that the load will be too much and I will need serious pillars there. A smaller gate is preferable, there is an access path next to the boat that will be used to bring to the street the garbage bins behind the boat. It will not be very convenient to open the big gate every time just for that

Comment: You could do a wide gate section to allow the boat in and out, and a smaller gate section to get the cans in and out.  A wheel on the large gate section could prevent it from sagging, and make opening and closing it easier.

Comment: I was hoping for something simpler. Working with wood is something that I could do but working with iron,steel etc not really. The wheels and their track will also be problematic for me not only technically but because I will need extend a rain gutter to drain on my driveway. I could probably leave some room there but that is another topic that I want to discuss with you guys. 
I was thinking of a light weight modular fence with removable posts.

Comment: **Nothing** about a wood fence is light weight enough to lend itself to easy removal like you describe. Maybe you need chain-link panels with posts that drop into holes at grade, which you could lift and remove when needed. You could weave some thin wood lath or wood-colored vinyl strips through the chain-link to block view through it.

Comment: I think you need to better define your requirements, otherwise we're just shooting in the dark. How tall of a fence do you want?  Do you have any ideas of your own? Is there anything that's completely unwanted?  Some photos of the area might also be helpful.

Comment: Nope that is about all that is unwanted. I added a picture, see the initial message

Answer (score 1):

Are you permitted to build out into the driveway toward the street? You could sink a post to the left and right (anchoring the right post to the face of the brick garage). Frame it across the top, hang an upper tubular guide, and build a hanging sliding panel in front of the boat. The panel would span the left ~2/3 of the opening in front of the boat and roll to the right when access is needed.

You could frame up a smaller swinging gate to the right of where the sliding panel is. The sliding panel would cover the swinging gate and part of the garage when open, when closed it  would be like a fence. Something kinda like this:

[image]

Comment: Nice solution but it is to complicated for me, please see my comment above

Comment: You might want to hire this done rather than DIY. Wood weighs like tree; a large moving solid wood object isn't going to be simple.